# From pandas dataframe of objects to pandas dataframe of methods

Tags: pandas, dataframe, class, object, series

Suppose you have some class with method_1.

Suppose you have dataframe : elements = objects of this class.

How to get dataframe : elements = method_1 of each object?

Comment: Do you mean how to access the method_1 for each element, or to store the method as the element?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.method_1)
```

you can define on the fly function and inside manipulate with your single object as you want.